# Null Coalescing for String to Int

Tags: c#, coalesce

I want to do a checking on a textbox, if null then assign zero, after that proceed with some calculation. I know there is a null coalescing (??) operator can help me, but I'm not sure is it possible for me to assign int when textbox is empty.

I tried to write something like this, but seems like is an error.

```
sdowntime = Convert.ToInt32(txtSDown.Text) ?? 0;
```

I get this

> Error 98  Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

Anything I made it wrong or actually I should use another method? Please guide. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` could not possibly return null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use the `TryParse` method, like so:

```
int sdowntime;
int.TryParse(txtSDown.Text, out sdowntime);
```

If the `TextBox` is blank or contains a non-numeric value, the `out` parameter will be assigned the value 0. Otherwise, the appropriately parsed value is assigned. Please note, however, that you should always have client-side validation to ensure that non-numeric values are not entered by users in numeric fields.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because `int` is a value type. And since value types are not `null`-able, it is meaningless to use null-coalescing operator on them.

<strike>What you really need to do is check the `null`-ness of the text:</strike>

```
string textToParse = txtDown.Text ?? "0";
```

**Edit**: So I made a mistake and it has been pointed out that `TextBox.Text` can never be `null`.

**Extra**:

Even if you check for null, `Convert.ToInt32` can fail if your text is not `null`, but empty (`""` or `String.Empty`). You can use `int.TryParse`.

```
int sdowntime;

if (!int.TryParse(txtDown.Text ?? "0", out sdowntime))
{
    // int.TryParse will assign 0 to sdowntime if it fails
    // so watch out for that too.
}
```

Comment: The `Text` of a `TextBox` can never be `null`. If the `TextBox` is empty then it will be `String.Empty`.